# How to check size of library document file before uploaded with event receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm new in sharepoint environment, but i have a question
**I wanna Create An Event Receiver to check the size of file in library that's user will upload**,
because I want to reject sizes bigger than 1 MB.

any help will be appreciated

What I have tried:
**I'm tried catch the attachment file to get it's size but I can't !**

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties){
        using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://win-sp:1001/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPDocumentLibrary oLibrary = oSPWeb.Lists["myLibrary"] as SPDocumentLibrary;

                if (oLibrary != null)
                {
                    properties.BeforeProperties["Title"].ToString(); 
                }
            }
        }
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and modify the below mentioned code:

We need to use either the `properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"]` or `properties.ListItem.File.TotalLength` to check the file size.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
     long validFileSize  = 1000000;//1MB;
     long currentFileSize;
     if (properties.ListItem == null)
     {
             using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
             {                   
                 if (properties.ListTitle.ToLower() == "myLibrary")
                 {                       
                      currentFileSize = long.Parse(properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"].ToString());
                      if (currentFileSize > validFileSize)
                      {
                            return false;
                      }
                }                 
          }
    }
    else if (properties.ListItem.ParentList.Title.ToLower() == "myLibrary")
    {         
                currentFileSize = properties.ListItem.File.TotalLength;
                if (currentFileSize > validFileSize)
                {
                      return false;
                }

    }
    return true;
}
```